# How to test a Jenkins pipeline (or other jenkins script) that makes use of the branch name?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

If I have a Jenkins pipeline script (though the principle could apply to any Jenkins script really) that has different behaviours depending on which branch is getting built, how can I test that it's working properly without merging it into that branch?  In the pipeline script it's tested both using the `branch` keyword and by testing env.BRANCH_NAME.  I'd think the latter might be something you could override somehow but I can see how.

Just to clarify, I have this at the top of my Jenkinsfile:

```
def isSpecialBranch = env.BRANCH_NAME ==~ *reg-ex*
```

Plus there are also a number of nodes that have

```
when { 
    branch 'xxxxx'
}
```

Basically I want to test that the pipeline will behave correctly once the changes are merged to a branch-name that does fit the pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Jenkins Pipeline Unit](https://github.com/jenkinsci/JenkinsPipelineUnit) in order to *mock* the branches.

You can even mock [Jenkins variables](https://github.com/jenkinsci/JenkinsPipelineUnit#mock-jenkins-variables) and that kind of stuff.

Anyway, the proper way to write the when expression is something like this (e.g to match master):

```
when {
       expression { (branch == 'origin/master') }
}
```

or (e.g. to match develop, feature or hotfix)

```
when {
     expression { (branch == 'origin/develop' || branch.matches('origin\\/(feature|hotfix)+\\/.*')) }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Looks very useful, will definitely investigate!  At the moment I keep breaking my develop branch builds...

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
static def getBranchName(scm)
{
  return scm.branches[0].name
}
```

This need to run with elevated privileges so this is part of my Utilities class in my shared library.

Comment: But surely that's even *harder* to override than env.BRANCH_NAME?   The point is I want to test that it's doing the right thing when the branch name is, e.g., "master" before actually merging into 'master'.

Comment: The env.BRACH_NAME is not always available. I think it is only available for multi branch pipelines.